# Django 1.6 A.objects.all().order_by(['field']) what will django do if the 'field' is the default order in a model?

Tags: django

Say I have a Question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    title = models.CharField()
```

If you define ordering in Meta, is it just a default setting for you to type less words, so the performances of `Question.objects.all().order_by(['title'])` and `Question.objects.all()` will be the same?

Comment: As you know, a RDBMS don't store rows in any order ( but clustered idexes ... ) The right question may be if `ordering` create an index in database. You can answer yourself this question easily with a simple [`sqlindexes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlindexes-app-label-app-label) command. And yes, set ordering in Meta avoid you to call `order_by` in each query (DRY).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, performance is the same. Specifying `Meta.ordering` acts exactly like appending `order_by` to each query.

You can watch SQL queries that Django generates by setting DEBUG level for logger `django.db.backends`.

Example models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    dummy = models.TextField()


class ModelB(models.Model):
    dummy = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['dummy']
```

SQL queries examples:

```
>>> import logging
>>> l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
>>> l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

>>> from sqlorder.models import ModelA, ModelB
>>> ModelA.objects.all()
(0.111) SELECT "sqlorder_modela"."id", "sqlorder_modela"."dummy" 
FROM "sqlorder_modela" LIMIT 21; args=()
[]
```

`ModelA` has no ordering by default, so ModelA.objects.all does not appends `ORDER BY` to query. You can append it manually.

```
>>> ModelA.objects.order_by('dummy')
(0.001) SELECT "sqlorder_modela"."id", "sqlorder_modela"."dummy" 
FROM "sqlorder_modela" 
ORDER BY "sqlorder_modela"."dummy" ASC LIMIT 21; args=()
[]
```

`ModelB` has default ordering. Query is the same as for `ModelA` with manual addition of `order_by`.

```
>>> ModelB.objects.all()
(0.001) SELECT "sqlorder_modelb"."id", "sqlorder_modelb"."dummy" 
FROM "sqlorder_modelb" 
ORDER BY "sqlorder_modelb"."dummy" ASC LIMIT 21; args=()
[]
```

**Update:** 
Default ordering does not adds any additional indices to database:

```
$ python manage.py sqlall sqlorder
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "sqlorder_modela" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "dummy" text NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "sqlorder_modelb" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "dummy" text NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for telling the answer and more importantly showing how it comes.